# Retrieve List/Library "Shared With" Users and Groups using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, csom, jsom

I can retrieve **Shared With** info from a SharePoint 2013 (On Premisses) List/Library (not an item) using Javascript?

I thought it could be available through `SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getObjectSharingInformation` method, but I´m stucked on `getSharedWithUsers()` method throwing an error like **The collection has not been initialized**.

Should I load other properties in context?

My bitcode, trying to get a simple count of shared users/groups:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
ctx.load(list);
var su = SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getObjectSharingInformation(ctx, list);
console.log(su.getSharedWithUsers().get_count());
```

Error:

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Few things are missing

1. Loading `su.getSharedWithUsers()`
2. Calling `ctx.executeQueryAsync()`

## Modified code

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
var su = SP.ObjectSharingInformation.getObjectSharingInformation(ctx, list);

var sharedWithUsers = su.getSharedWithUsers();
ctx.load(sharedWithUsers);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    console.log(sharedWithUsers.get_count());
}, function() {

});
```

Comment: Atish, thank you very much. With your help I could understand better how it works and move forward to loop through those items, retrieving all values I needed. Thanks! :)
`ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {`
`var sharedEnumerator = sharedWithUsers.getEnumerator();`
`while (sharedEnumerator.moveNext()) {`
`var usr = sharedEnumerator.get_current();`
`console.log(usr.get_name());`
`}`
`}, function (sender, args){`
`alert('Request failed retrieving Shared Users. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); `
`});`